# Does Sqlite have a table, view, and/or column description in the metadata?

Tags: c#, sqlite, dbconnection, getschema

I am calling DbConnection.GetSchema("Tables") and that does not return a column named "table_comment".

Does Sqlite not have descriptions in its metadata?

Or if it has it, how do I query it?

thanks - dave

Comment: It seems that they don't have it. You cannot even set a comment when creating the table https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Comment: @Steve - thank you. If you post that as an answer I'm happy to select it.

Comment: I have not enough experience on SQLite to be conclusive with an answer. Let's see if some SQLite expert comes here with more certainty

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure this is what you're asking, but `DbConnection.GetSchema("MetaDataCollections")` will help you find all of the arguments that the `GetSchema()` method can take. These methods include views and columns. The `"Tables"` argument only returns a list of the tables. If by description you are referring to something similar to a MySQL `DESCRIBE`, you can query the `sqlite_master` to see the `create` statements. That's the closest I know of to comments (though there could certainly be ways I don't know of).